# using reflection and linq for dynamic linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, expression-trees

I wrote this code:

```
string Dcname = "DataClasses1DataContext";
string TableName = "Order";
var dc =(DataContext)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(DataContext), Dcname);
ITable mytbl=(ITable)dc.GetType().GetProperty(TableName).GetValue(dc,null);
```

I want to query mytable using linq or Expression Tree.

How I can do this?

Comment: IF you really want to do it this way then I would suggest that you should not use LINQ. LINQ it for "type safe queries" which is not there when you use reflection. You will end up in really messy code

Comment: you are right but I should do that

Comment: Why do you want to do that? the answer to your question depends on the goal you are trying to achieve, so please give us some context.

Comment: I want to create a Extended `Gridview` that It can get `DataContext` name and Table Name and show some data of it.I want my Gridview query table using `Expression Tree`(Or if i can by `linq`) according some conditions and show them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use [Linq compiler](http://linqcompiler.codeplex.com/) for such scenario.